# change connection string on asp.net core project (appsettings.json)

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm publishing web application on asp.net core via Visual Studio. connectionstring is in `appsettings.json`.   How to change it?

In MVC5 projects i stored transformations in profiles (`web.[profileName].config` or `Web.Release.Config`) writing this way:

```
<add name="string"  connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DevDb;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=passwd" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have environment specific `appsettings.json` files, for e.g. `appsettings.Development.json` by calling following in your `Startup()` method:

```
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

Refer to [Asp.Core Configuration](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) page.